# Swagger Code generation with minItems and maxLength for items

Tags: swagger, swagger-2.0, swagger-codegen

I would like to post an array of strings with min items of 2 and max length of 50 for the strings inside the array.
I set up my swagger like so :

```
"values":{
"desciption":"values of file",
"type":"array",
"items":{
   "type":"string",
   "maxLength": 50
},
"minItems": 2
}
```

but for some reason in the codegen it only takes the minItems without taking into consideration the maxLength I can type 50+ characters and it passes

Comment: Which server/client did you generate with codegen?

Comment: "desciption" spelling mistake. and everything is correct. But maxLength is not working for elements as string of array. So, please raise a BUG Via https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator/issues/new?assignees=&labels=Issue%3A+Bug&template=bug_report.md&title=%5BBUG%5D+Description

Answer (score 0):

I find your definition within yml is correct, and even code is not generated correctly. So, I will advise raising a separate bug for this will help other users as well.

Even there are some of the bugs that are not working for example `minItems: and maxItems:` for the same list doesn't restrict or code is not generating is not automatically for this behavior. @Size(min=2,max=4) i.e.

```
       values:
          description: values of file
          type: array
          items:
            type: string
            maxLength: 20
          minItems: 2
          maxItems: 4
```

So I will suggest you raise a separate bug through the given link:
https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator/issues/new?assignees=&labels=Issue%3A+Bug&template=bug_report.md&title=%5BBUG%5D+Description

Answer (score 0):

There are at least two different open issues related to this problem (assuming you want to generate java code):

https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator/issues/10026
https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator/issues/4947

Even the swagger-api code-generator (https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen) does have the same issue.

IMHO, everything boils down to a problem with the mustache templates and the underlying java code that can not use BeanValidation 2.0 features like:

https://beanvalidation.org/2.0/spec/#constraintdeclarationvalidationprocess-containerelementconstraints

```
List<@NotNull @Size(max=20) String> searchTerms
```